# Unable to call javascript from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

On the click of a button this Javascript is called:

```
var xmlhttp;
function register()
{   
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    alert("pass");
    if(xmlhttp==null)
    {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }
    var url="register.php";
    url=url+"?id="+uniqueid+"&name="+name+"&passwrd="+passwrd1+"&email="+email;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=statechanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
}

function statechanged()
{
    //alert("statechanged function");
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;
}

function testing()
{
    document.getElementById("mainbody").innerHTML="This is my first JavaScript!";
}
```

And then this PHP script is called:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">testing();</script>";
?>
```

The HTML has two `DIV` tags with IDs of `mainbody` and `response`:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT SRC=javascriptname.js></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <DIV ID=mainbody>
     <DIV ID=response>
     </DIV>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am unable to call the javascript from my php. 
If anyone know what I am doing wrong or has an idea what I should do, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Clean up your question if you're expecting anyone to take this seriously. Also, using ALL CAPS is annoying.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up your question. -1 removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think changing the innerHTML of an object and inserting a script will cause it to fire.  I certainly wouldn't want to depend on that behavior.

Why not just do some kind of string comparison on the responseText, (in a case statement, for example) and then call the appropriate function?

EDIT:  You could also remove the script tags, and call eval on the responseText, but eval is not the nicest function in the world.

Comment: Well i was thinking of the same, but it will not be a very good way as per my code requirement. it would be my last option

Comment: I agree, the script will not fire on a dynamic update. Any way you can change your quite odd code requirement?

Comment: what i am doing is, creating a register form, if there are errors i show it in the response div tag, and if there are no errors, i want to show the result in mainbody div tag. do you think there is some other way i should do it??

Comment: If you really want a script tag in your DOM, you could create one via document.createElement, set the innerHTML to your your response text (like 'testing()') and then put it in your head.  All done in your statechanged function.  But that's essentially eval....and what I'm suggesting is just weird.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully done this by passing the script tags within the string

Example:

```
<?php
function outputResults($var1)
{
   $jsStringOut = "
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.write('".$var1."');
   </script>
   ";

   return $jsStringOut;
}

echo outputResults("Hello Stackers");
?>
```